# Working Apex test class no longer works after being deployed

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Well, I'm confused. A few months ago, I got a working apex class and test class configured to generate a Quote PDF document and email it. I had 99% code coverage and deployed it. I went back to modify it today and the test class now reports "Add test methods to your test class." I reloaded the original working apex code, same error. I have a plugin in my browser to access the developer console in production, so I tried the test class there and same error. I compared it to a test class a past developer wrote and it's written the exact same way, with the exception of the "quoteIds", and it works. Can someone please tell me why it no longer works?

```
@isTest
private class generateQuotePdfDocumentTest {

@testSetup
static void setup() {

(basic object setup, nothing fancy)

Test.startTest();
generateQuotePdfDocument.createQuote(quoteIds);
Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Apex class being referenced

```
Public class generateQuotePdfDocument{

@InvocableMethod   
public static void createQuote(List<Id> quoteIds)  
{ 
    createQuoteFutureMethod(quoteIds);
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void createQuoteFutureMethod (List<Id> quoteIds) {
```

Comment: Do you have any test methods in your test class? All I'm seeing with your truncated example is an `@testSetup` method. As the name suggests, that's what you use to set up data for the rest of your tests. It doesn't (or shouldn't) have ever been getting executed if you don't have any test methods. Also, it doesn't look like you have any assertions (which are the most important part of a unit test).

Comment: Also, for reference, I don't use assertions in this because it's absolutely basic. It either works or it doesn't. There's nothing to validate because if it doesn't work, there's nothing to assert, only fix. I am mainly a Flow user, but some things I need to go into Apex for. This was one of them. It's been working for months without any issue. I just had to make some adjustments to allow for extra variables, but also realizing I did it inefficiently (2 SOQLs on the same object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, thank you @derek. I changed it to isTest and that fixed it, back to 98% coverage. How odd that it worked for me in the past. But I understand my mistake now.